# Draw a rectangle using the graphics class, but move the registration point

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, registration

I have the following code to create a Sprite with a rectangle in it:

```
container = new Sprite();
container.graphics.beginFill(0x00CCFF, .5);
container.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x00CCFF);
container.graphics.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
container.graphics.endFill()
addChild(container);
```

The only thing is, I'd like the registration point to be in the middle (not the top left corner). Is there a way to set up the registration point in the middle of the rectangle, but still have the position of the rectangle be correct?

i.e. *not* moved over so that the top left corner of the rectangle is in the "middle" of where I want the rectangle to be...

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650567/as3-setting-registration-point-of-a-displayobject-with-actionscript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can do is:

```
container.graphics.drawRect(rect.x-rect.width/2, rect.y-rect.height/2, rect.width, rect.height);
```

But I think that is what you are saying you don't want to do. Although, there might be a way it can be done with a Matrix.

Edit:

It looks like this [other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650567/as3-setting-registration-point-of-a-displayobject-with-actionscript) might have some more answers for you regarding using a transform matrix, and a few other possibilities.